# Django - Serving statics with views and not with django.contrib.staticfiles

Tags: django

Im new in DJango and I need to change current static serving mode removing the /static Alias from Apache configuration (and relative STATIC_URL from default_settings)

```
 Alias /static/           /usr/local/app/static/
```

On django settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

to a internal serving services using a local view.

I have added a new constant in settings.py

```
STATIC_WEB_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/frontend/')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

url(r'^%sstatic/(?P<path>.*)$' % , static  , {'document_root': STATIC_WEB_ROOT }, name='static.file.serve'),
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'static.file.serve' 'frontend/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'                    %}" ></script>
```

Unfortunally, I get a 404:

```
"GET /static/frontend/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? This is the wrong way round.

Comment: If you have multiple web-application on server and all of them has its own static, you have to add aliases in apache config virtual host for everyone,  manage contingent proxy settings for them etc... This add a lot of sys-admin efforts during configuration/migration/restoring etc...
If I need to add a /media, I can simply create a view in DJango without adding new alasis to apache etc...

Comment: No, you really can't. The documentation is absolutely clear that this is not suitable for serving in production. If you really want your app server to serve the static files, use something like Whitenoise.

Answer (score 0):

My settings was wrong in two points:

The correct module to import in urls.py is:

```
from django.views.static import serve
```

In default settings you have to disable, if exists:

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles'
```

that is the classical way to expose statics

Then in the url you can use:

```
url(r'^%sstatic/(?P<path>.*)$' % BASE_URL_PREFIX  , serve  , {'document_root': STATIC_WEB_ROOT }, name='static.file.serve'),
```